# Can I search only some of the fields of a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I want to create a custom post type with fields: Text1, text2 and text3.

I want to make this custom post type searchable.

But searchable fields will only be Text1, and text2.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With WP's default search - no.

But you can with [this plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-unleashed/). Select "Lucene" or "Mysql Fulltext" (Zend Lucene is a little faster) as the search engine, check the "post meta" module and select the meta fields you want to search in the module settings. Then re-index

You'll also have to edit the models/spider.php from the plugin dir to include custom post types - Search for instances of `{$wpdb->posts}.post_type` and add the appropriate custom post type slug there...

Comment: great, I ll try search unleashed.